# Changing the value of textbox based on checkboxes and another textbox

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, textbox

I have a textbox that shows the decimal value when certain checkboxes are checked having some values. The value in the textbox that is displayed is obtained by adding the values assigned to the checkboxes and a value from a different textbox.

for example :

If 2 checkboxes are checked then the value is 16+8 =24 and the value in the textbox is 2. The code I have used applies to every checkbox given below

```
If CheckBox3.Checked <> 0 Then
        ALMvalue = 16 + Convert.ToInt32(TextBox30.Text) + ALMvalue
        TextBox3.Text = ALMvalue.ToString("X4")

    Else
        ALMvalue = ALMvalue - 16 - Convert.ToInt32(TextBox30.Text)
        TextBox3.Text = ALMvalue.ToString("X4")
    End If
```

The issue here is that, the value that we are getting from the different textbox keeps aggregating and shows the wrong value. So, if both checkboxes are clicked and the value in the textbox is 2. then it produces the output 8+16+4 (instead of 8+16+2). Is there any way to see if the value in the textbox is unchanged or changed before adding the values.

Let me know if I can improve the question in any way .I am new to vb

Comment: Your question is very unclear but `ALMvalue = 16 + Convert.ToInt32(TextBox30.Text) + ALMvalue` is keeping the old value by adding it back in

Comment: @Plutonix Yea, because there are multiple checkboxes, so if 2 checkboxes are checked then it adds both values.